# Как определить классы, чтобы объект класса или его члены можно было использовать в другом и наоборот

Tags: c++

Как заставить подобный код работать:

```
class A {
B::size_type sz;
public:
A(B::size_type s) :sz{ s } {}
};

class B {
A a;
public:
using size_type = unsigned int;
B(size_type aa) :a{ aa } {}
};
```

Comment: Не меняя работу программы - никак. Надо выбросить `using` из класса.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такой способ решения, в заголовочном файле надо определить классы, без реализации конструктора класса B, и использовать указатель на класс A:

```
class A;

class B {
  std::unique_ptr<A> a;
public:
  using size_type = unsigned int;
  B(size_type aa);
};

class A {
 B::size_type sz;
public:
 A(B::size_type s) :sz{ s } {}
};
```

А в файле .cpp определить конструктор класса B:

```
B::B(B::size_type aa) :a {std::make_unique<A>(aa)}
{

}
```